# JSON partial text string search to return conditional formatting - SharePoint Calendar

Tags: json

Problem: I want to search the description for "Vacation" in a string that reads "Name (Vacation)". there are many different Names, Name 1, Name 2, etc. the word "Vacation" is constant, I want to create 1 condition that formats all variations of Vacation.

I have played around with the operator changing "operator": "==", with no luck. Example "in", "$in", etc.

Is there an easy solution that I am missing?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/calendar-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalEventClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          "[$Title_x0020_Category]",
          "Name (Vacation)"
        ]
      },
      "=if(@isSelected == true, 'sp-css-color-WhiteFont sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGreen' , 'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont')",
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I want to search the description for "Vacation" in a string that reads "Name (Vacation)". there are many different Names, Name 1, Name 2, etc. the word "Vacation" is constant, I want to create 1 condition that formats all variations of Vacation.